# Do I need to run the MVC 4 installer for VS 2010 if I install it via NuGet?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't have permission to run installers on my work machine which only has Visual Studio 2010 (no service pack). However NuGet packages seem to install with no problem.

For a new web app I would *at least* try to use MVC 4 which is listed as available.

Do I still need to run the MVC 4 windows installer? will I have any problems when deploying to the production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime will work, but project templates, debugger support and intellisense will not work on your visual studio instance.

PS: It's crazy not to have the updates for Visual Studio installed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah I know!! I just started working at a bank last week and apparently their work stations are crazy limited for security reasons.

Comment: Show them the list of security issues in the RTM install of VS2010, maybe that'll convince them. Security is attained by keeping current, not by staying put.